# What is the subject of "reducing"?

Tags: subjects, participles

> Others will say we can reduce traffic without damaging the environment. For example, public transportation could be improved, **reducing** the cars on the roads.

What is the subject of "reducing"?
a) public transportation
b) public transportation could be improved (i.e. the previous whole clause)

I cannot decide which one is right. It seems to me that all of them make sense. If one is a definite answer, I want to know why the other one is not.

Comment: No, it doesn't because I'm not a native even if I know a general rule, I cannot find out what is right in each cases.

Comment: Like most non-finite clauses, it has no overt subject, but in a sense we _understand_ it as having a subject, in this case "an improvement in public transportation".

Comment: Oh, thank goodness. I really appreciate your answer BillJ. Please could you answer another question of mine? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270659/what-is-the-subject-of-helping-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to ask, what is it that *reduces* the number of cars in this argument? Your two options are:

- public transport
- the act of improving public transport

Since we can assume that public transport already exists (otherwise it would be hard to improve it!) then we're not introducing it - there's no change being effected, so that wouldn't cause a reduction in car use.

On the other hand, *improving public transport* **is** a thing that implies consequences, so it would make sense to say that might *reduce the cars on the roads*.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example of "The sirens sounded, indicating that the air raid was over," which was in your textbook, I would say that subject of "reducing" is "public transportation could be improved."  You can re-phrase that sentence as: "For example, public transportation could be improved, which would reduce the cars on the roads." (Note: I would say, "which would reduce *the number of* cars on the roads.")